# Symfony | Forms | Self-referencing CollectionType field - ERROR: out of memory

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

First of all we are using **Symfony 3.4**.

We have a **self-referencing field** `children` on an Entity `Category`. So a category can have category-children and those category-children can have category-children and so on...

```
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AcmeBundle\Entity\Category", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $children;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AcmeBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="children")
     */
    private $parent;
}
```

Now we created an API and use the **form functionality** of Symfony to validate and create the objects & data. So for the categories we created this FormType:

```
class CategoryType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('children', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => CategoryType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'mapped' => false,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ]);
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AcmeBundle\Entity\Category'
        ));
    }
}
```

This is an example of the **API data array** that is sent to the backend:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
        ["title"]=>
        string(9) "Backlight"
        ["children"]=>
        array(3) {
            [0]=>
            array(2) {
                ["title"]=>
                string(10) "Technology"
                ["children"]=>
                array(0) {
                }
            }
            [1]=>
            array(2) {
                ["title"]=>
                string(12) "Panel mount "
                ["children"]=>
                array(0) {
                }
            }
            [2]=>
            array(2) {
                ["title"]=>
                string(11) "OEM modules"
                ["children"]=>
                array(0) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
        ["title"]=>
        string(13) "Ball diameter"
        ["children"]=>
        array(2) {
            [0]=>
            array(2) {
                ["title"]=>
                string(18) "No pointing device"
                ["children"]=>
                array(0) {
                }
            }
            [1]=>
            array(2) {
                ["title"]=>
                string(9) "Trackball"
                ["children"]=>
                array(0) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when we do the save and run this code we get this **error**:

```
[09-Aug-2018 14:41:13 Europe/Paris] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/acme-project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/OptionsResolver/OptionsResolver.php on line 865
[09-Aug-2018 14:41:13 Europe/Paris] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/acme-project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/Exception/OutOfMemoryException.php on line 1
```

Sooooo, it **seems** that it gets stuck in en **infinite loop** of creating FormTypes because he is creating and endless collection of children->children->children->... (The `OptionsResolver` is the parameter for the `configureOptions()` function in a FormType)

So **my question** is, is this even possible with the Form functionality? Or how should I program this? Or will I have to cut out the saving of Categories from the Symfony-Form-functionality and have to write my own recursive save-function?

I've seen **other people** asking the same thing and also not getting an answer:
http://forum.symfony-project.org/forum/23/topic/70753.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use form events the same way as described here in symphony docs https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms
attaching the `PRE_SET_DATA` event on the main form and the `POST_SUBMIT` event on the `title` field.

You will add the `children` field in the form modifier if and only if the data is either in your model or in the user's submitted data, thus stopping recursion.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that as soon as possible.